# Understanding Python Descriptors

Tags: python, descriptor, python-descriptors

I am trying to understand descriptors better.

I don't understand why in the foo method the descriptors *`__get__`* method doesn't get called.

As far as I understand descriptors the *`__get__`* method always get called when I access the objects attribute via dot operator or when I use `__getattribute__()`.

According to the [Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/descriptor.html#descriptor-protocol):

```
class RevealAccess(object):
    def __init__(self, initval=None, name='var'):
        self.val = initval
        self.name = name

    def __get__(self, obj, objtype):
        print('Retrieving', self.name)
        return self.val

    def __set__(self, obj, val):
        print('Updating', self.name)
        self.val = val

class MyClass(object):
    x = RevealAccess(10, 'var "x"')
    y = 5

    def foo(self):
        self.z = RevealAccess(13, 'var "z"')
        self.__getattribute__('z')
        print(self.z)

m = MyClass()
m.foo()
m.z # no print
m.x # prints var x
```

Comment: I don't exactly understand what your problem is?

Comment: @user3467349: `m.z` and `m.x` are both instances of the class `RevealAccess`, which implements the descriptor protocol. The OP expected the protocol to be used for both `m.z` and `m.x`.

Comment: @user3467349: e.g. you need to understand what the descriptor protocol *is* before you can answer the question.

Comment: m.z returns exactly the instance that was assigned to it for me, I'm still not sure what the expected output is here?

Comment: Does he mean to call `m.z.__getattribute__` ? MyClass is not subclassing  RevealClass...

Comment: @user3467349: no, they don't. They are reading the descriptor protocol documentation, which explains that attribute access on `m` is handled by `type(m).__getattribute__(attribute)` and that that is where the descriptor protocol is executed.

Comment: @user3467349: the expected output is `Retrieving var "z"`; e.g. the `RevealAccess.__get__` method was called.

Comment: @MartijnPieters The docs don't suggest that the `RevealAccess.__get__` method would be called at all - unless you are reading something different from what the OP linked.

Comment: @user3467349: under Invoking Descriptors, the process is laid out. The example in the question is taken directly from that HOWTO.

Comment: @user3467349: No, the descriptor protocol is not used for instance attributes, as my answer explains. `RevealAccess.__get__` *is* called when `m.x` is accessed.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`z` is an attribute on the *instance*, not on the class. The descriptor protocol only applies to attributes retrieved from a class.

From the [Descriptor HOWTO](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html#invoking-descriptors):

> For objects, the machinery is in `object.__getattribute__()` which transforms `b.x` into `type(b).__dict__['x'].__get__(b, type(b))`.

and in the [*Implementing Descriptors* section](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#implementing-descriptors) of the Python Data Model:

> The following methods only apply when an instance of the class containing the method (a so-called *descriptor* class) appears in an *owner* class (the descriptor must be in either the owner’s class dictionary or in the class dictionary for one of its parents).

Your `m.z` cannot be found in the class dict; `type(m).__dict__['z']` does not exist; it is found in `m.__dict__['z']` instead. Here `m` is the instance and the *owner* class is `MyClass`, and `z` does not appear in the *owner* class dictionary.